# Does node.js guarantee that fs.read() always fills the buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider a rather typical fs.read/fs.readSync usage (example code from https://github.com/kodie/md5-file/blob/master/index.js)

```
  const BUFFER_SIZE = 8192
  const fd = fs.openSync(path, 'r')
  const buffer = Buffer.alloc(BUFFER_SIZE)
  do {
    bytesRead = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)
    // do something with buffer[0..bytesRead]
  } while (bytesRead === BUFFER_SIZE)
```

This stops reading as soon as a single read call no longer fills the whole buffer - instead of checking that the read call has read 0 bytes.

Since the underlying OS calls to read can return incomplete buffers ([linux read()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) mentions reading named pipes as an example and I can't find the documentation, but I am sure I read that Windows could return partial buffers when reading from network disks), the question is - is node.js adding some additional checks to ensure the buffer is fully filled unless EOF is reached or is this example code simply wrong?

Comment: If that code were in C on a Linux machine I would consider it wrong. I mean, what's the point of the `.slice()` if it's expected that every buffer will be perfectly filled?

Comment: i agree the slice is strange on its own, but that would impact perf, not correctness of the code, so that is not the focus of the question

Comment: Sure, but still; I would not write code like that. It seems needlessly fragile, even if the buffer is always reliably filled.

Comment: The answer here would come from examination of the actual code that does the read, both  the JS wrapper and the underlying C++ code.  I could find most of the relevant code in the repository, but not follow it all to answer the question.  Here are some places to look: [Underlying libuv `uv_fs_read()` function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b6b65101873c32655c8d71b4d73363d624f58770/deps/uv/src/unix/fs.c#L1983), [Wrapper where `uv_fs_read()` is called from](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8f248d43b9db0ccd9f23be0e771844907a330156/src/node_file.cc#L486).